# Android Design 2 Images and text LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a layout like this:

[image: Layout I'm trying to achieve]

Basically I have 2 Images that I would like to stick to either side of the LinearLayout and in the center have some text. I'm setting the width of the images in code based on the density of the screen, so that is of variable width.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/user_loading_wrapper"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_spacing">

        <!--User Poster-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_poster"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="User Poster"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <!--Review Details-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/screen_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_poster"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_spacing_max"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--User Title-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <!--Location-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <!--User 2 Title-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_secondary_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                tools:text="Life of Pi"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--Poster-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_poster_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/screen_details"
            android:contentDescription="Poster"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

But it doesn't work at all. I want the Center Layout to expand and occupy all the space in the middle between the two images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it .... check output it in image and flow in code.
[image]

And Code is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/user_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_poster"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/screen_details"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Life of Pi"
            android:textColor="#333" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Life of Pi"
            android:textColor="#333" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_secondary_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Life of Pi"
            android:textColor="#333" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_poster2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Fantastic! This works. I need to read up more on the layout_weights. Could you give a brief explanation on why you have set weights of 1 and 0 for the screen_details and user_poster2 respectively? Thanks for the solution!

Comment: feeling happy :). It's simple my friend. In linear layout, items are placed in linear order. So first image and layout(screen_details) comes in order as required. While for Layout (screen_detail), i am assigning weight 1 so that it will occupy all left space. whereas, 0 weight force to shows the image (user_poster) at the bottom with the size of it's width and height

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/user_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <!--User Poster-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_poster"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="User Poster"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <!--Review Details-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/screen_details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_poster"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!--User Title-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <!--Location-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <!--User 2 Title-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_secondary_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Life of Pi"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Poster-->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_poster_2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="Poster" />

</RelativeLayout>
```